# Python Logging StreamHandler isn't logging from modules

Tags: python, logging

I have a very simple structure. But only one of my two logging handlers is logging from my modules:

program.py,
support_module1.py,
support_module2.py

```
#program.py
import support_module1 as SM1
import support_module1 as SM2
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='/logs/TestLog.log',
    filemode='w',
    level='DEBUG',
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[logging.FileHandler(r'/logs/TestLog.log')])
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(stdout_handler)

log.debug("shows in file")
log.info("shows in file and in stdout")
SM1.function1()
SM2.function2()
```

Modules

```
#support_module1.py
mod1_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

function1():
    mod1_log.debug("shows in file")
    mod1_log.info("should show in file and in stdout, but only goes to file")


#support_module2.py
mod2_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

function2():
    mod2_log.debug("shows in file")
    mod2_log.info("should show in file and in stdout, but only goes to file")
```

When I run I get:

```
shows in file and in stdout
```

I'm expecting:

```
shows in file and in stdout
should show in file and in stdout, but only goes to file
should show in file and in stdout, but only goes to file
```

Anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: In `program.py`, you are configuring `logging.getLogger(__name__)`. This will affect only the logger named `program.py` and thus only log records inside `program.py` itself. The `logging.getLogger(__name__)` inside `module1.py` will return a different logger named `module1.py` which is unaffected by the configuration in `program.py`.

Comment: The fix is very simple - replace `logging.getLogger(__name__)` with `logging.getLogger()` in `program.py`. This will configure the root logger instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hoefling pefectly explained why and how to fix. Thank you!

> In program.py, you are configuring logging.getLogger(**name**). This will affect only the logger named program.py and thus only log records inside program.py itself. The logging.getLogger(**name**) inside module1.py will return a different logger named module1.py which is unaffected by the configuration in program.py The fix is very simple - replace logging.getLogger(**name**) with logging.getLogger() in program.py. This will configure the root logger instead.
>   -hoefling